# BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletComponentRegisteringPostProcessor': Instantiation of supplied bean failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets

While learning java web servlet from Youtube videos i encountered this error whereas the tutorial not. This is still at the start of the tutorial and i don't know how spring works too. I just learned how to deploy manually by putting war file to webapps folder in tomcat folder and after this is how to deploy automatically by borrowing/using embedded tomcat spring boot (this is not a spring tutorial so he doesn't explain much about this).

There are just two file

1. BelajarServletApp.java

```
package yt.pzn.servlet;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletComponentScan;

@ServletComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class BelajarServletApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BelajarServletApp.class);
    }
}
```

2. HelloServlet.java file

```
package yt.pzn.servlet;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/halo", "/bang"})
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.getWriter().println("halo bang");
    }
}
```

This is what it said after i run it. What supposed to happen is the file is deployed on localhost port 8080 and no error occured. This isn't caused by used port right? port 8080 is free btw. So how do i fix this? and what is it caused by?

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.2)

2023-07-24T11:45:53.757+07:00  INFO 8752 --- [           main] yt.pzn.servlet.BelajarServletApp         : Starting BelajarServletApp using Java 17.0.7 with PID 8752 (C:\Coding Projects\belajar-java-web-servlet\target\classes started by USER in C:\Coding Projects\belajar-java-web-servlet)
2023-07-24T11:45:53.774+07:00  INFO 8752 --- [           main] yt.pzn.servlet.BelajarServletApp         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-07-24T11:45:55.441+07:00  WARN 8752 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletComponentRegisteringPostProcessor': Instantiation of supplied bean failed
2023-07-24T11:45:55.472+07:00  INFO 8752 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-07-24T11:45:55.553+07:00 ERROR 8752 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletComponentRegisteringPostProcessor': Instantiation of supplied bean failed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1220) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:199) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:771) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:589) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at yt.pzn.servlet.BelajarServletApp.main(BelajarServletApp.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/annotation/WebServlet
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.WebServletHandler.<init>(WebServletHandler.java:39) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletComponentRegisteringPostProcessor.<clinit>(ServletComponentRegisteringPostProcessor.java:49) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletComponentScanRegistrar$ServletComponentRegisteringPostProcessorBeanDefinition.lambda$getInstanceSupplier$0(ServletComponentScanRegistrar.java:96) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainInstanceFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.obtainInstanceFromSupplier(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    ... 22 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

```
pom.xml below if you need it.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>yt.pzn</groupId>
    <artifactId>belajar-java-web-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Belajar Java Web Servlet</name>
    <description>Belajar Java Web Servlet</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

please help me, thank you.

Comment: How are you running the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, Servlet API and related Java EE APIs must be provided by the web container (Tomcat) in runtime.
with a full-blown Tomcat servlet, these dependencies will be provided at runtime but this does not happen when using an embedded Tomcat.

There are two solutions.

**Solution 1: (Not recommended)**

change the scope of Tomcat from provided to compiled (comment or remove provided) to include the classes in the classpath.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Solution 2:**
Configure your IDE to add the provided dependencies to the classpath.

[Intellij IDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVYYh.png):

> Run -> Edit Configurations.. -> Build and Run -> Modify options ->
> add dependencies with provided scope to classpath